# Insert Id of previous inserted id into next insert in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, last-insert-id

I am performing Trigger Operation on tables. Where I want to Insert the Last ID into next insert. Because it's kind of log management. whenever any insert, update or delete operation will do automatically this trigger will be activated and insert operation will be performed. I have implemented only insert operation here but not understanding that how can I get last inserted id from 1st table. Here is my code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_auction_insert 
AFTER INSERT ON auction 
FOR EACH ROW
```

BEGIN

```
INSERT INTO udithdr(company_id, created_by, screen_name, action, action_date) VALUES (NEW.compid, NEW.user_id, "Auction", NEW.thought_type, NEW.created_time);

DECLARE audit_hdr_id_for_auction INT(20);

select NEW.audit_hdr_id into audit_hdr_id_for_auction;

INSERT INTO auditdtl(audit_hdr_id, col_name, old_value, new_value) VALUES (audit_hdr_id_for_auction, "title", OLD.title, NEW.title);
INSERT INTO auditdtl(audit_hdr_id, col_name, old_value, new_value) VALUES (audit_hdr_id_for_auction, "description", OLD.description, NEW.description);
```

END$$
DELIMITER ;

So from the code i want to insert the value of udithdr table's primary key into auditdtl's  audit_hdr_id.

Comment: In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: UPDATE auditdtl SET audit_hdr_id = audit_hdr_id_for_auction, col_name = "title", old_value = OLD.title, new_value = NEW.title;
ok P.Salmon but still getting the same error that There is no OLD row in insert trigger.

Comment: I don't think you are getting it - there is no OLD.title or OLD.description on an insert trigger on Auction and changing the INSERT INTO auditdtl to an update ain't going to change that.

Comment: you are right I am unable to do it but I want to insert that into the 2nd table then do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function.

Put `SET audit_hdr_id_for_auction = LAST_INSERT_ID();` after the `INSERT INTO udithdr ...`

Comment: INSERT INTO udithdr(company_id, created_by, screen_name, action, action_date) VALUES (NEW.compid, NEW.user_id, "Auction", NEW.thought_type, NEW.created_time) SET audit_hdr_id_for_auction = LAST_INSERT_ID(); like this?

Comment: Yes, that would give you the last inserted id, as must be evident by the name.

Comment: That's perfect but now unable to insert into "auditdtl" table. getting "There is no OLD row in insert trigger" error.

Comment: Why would you be surprised that there is no OLD on an insert?